# zsh alias -> function?

Tags: zsh, arguments

Suppose I have:

```
alias gg="git grep"
```

then stuff like:

```
gg "int x"
```

works, but

```
gg int x
```

gets complaints. Is there a way to rewrite gg as a function in zsh so that it takes all the arguments after gg, and stuffs them into a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
gg() { git grep "$*"; }
```

Comment: Uhm, to have them go into one string, you need `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` -- the form you wrote would pass them through as separate params, just like the alias.

Comment: This has the benefit of also being compatible with bash

Answer (score 6):

For your particular use case, this is a bad idea. `git-grep` is expecting a single-arg *pattern*. You're trying to get the shell to treat your space (between int and x) as part of the pattern. This will break quickly when you try something like: `gg foo.*bar` or various other things that the shell might interpret. So anything after `gg` really should be quoted. This is why `git grep int x` also doesn't work: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'x': unknown revision or path not in the working tree...`

If you think `gg` is a worthwhile keystroke saver, you should keep your arg to it consistent with what `git-grep` expects. Your original alias is fine for this. And continue to single- or double-quote your pattern, just like you do with any other regex-accepting command.

Comment: On the one hand it is very reasonable for a person to say "I reject the artificial need to manually quote things in a use-case where it is unambiguous what I want", on the other hand it's setting up a pitfall for yourself if habitually getting away without quoting leads you to accidentally forget to quote other special shell characters. But a user is not necessarily wrong for choosing the former, especially if they're informed.