# Executing a script in an alias

Tags: eclipse, alias, zshrc

I'm trying to alias `eclipse` to execute `eclipse -data $(pwd)`. However, for some reason adding this to my zshrc doesn't work:

`alias eclipse="eclipse -data $(pwd)"`

I can't seem to find the correct syntax - can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can use parameters in an alias (that's what [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904677/alias-with-parameters) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174298/zsh-alias-function) seem to indicate). You can instead define a function:

```
function eclipse () {
     eclipse -data "$(pwd)"
}
```

Of course, if you do that, running `eclipse` will give you:

```
eclipse: maximum nested function level reached
```

That's because once you define the function named `eclipse` that masks the external command, resulting in an infinite recursion loop.

Instead, you can use [command](http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?(zsh)Precommand%20Modifiers) to tell `zsh` to ignore any aliases or functions named `eclipse`:

```
function eclipse () {
     command eclipse -data "$(pwd)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you could use `command` for executing pwd:

```
alias eclipse="eclipse -data `pwd`"
```